# dataframe into dense vector spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

Acyally am working on spark 2.0.2
I would like to know , for example to work on logistic regression based on Spark ML.I would like to get each row of the dataframe into a vector which will be input for logistic regression , can you help get row resulted in the dataframe to get each row into a dense vector .Thanks.Here what i did to get the dataframe.

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.classification.LogisticRegression
import org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.{Vector, Vectors}
import org.apache.spark.ml.param.ParamMap
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.Display

object Example extends App {
val sparkSession = SparkSession.builder.master("local").appName("my-spark-app").getOrCreate()
val data=sparkSession.read.option("header", "true").csv("C://sample_lda_data.csv").toDF()
val data2=data.select("col2","col3","col4","col5","col6","col7","col8","col9")
```

at the end i want to get something like this as input for logistic regression
in the first position it will be the first column of the dataframe any help please

```
val data=sparkSession.read.option("header", "true").csv("C://sample_lda_data.csv").toDF()
val data2=data.select("col2","col3","col4","col5","col6","col7","col8","col9")
val assembler = new VectorAssembler().setInputCols(Array("col2", "col3", "col4")).setOutputCol("features")
val output = assembler.transform(data2)

main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Data type StringType is not supported.
```

I'll be so gratefull.Thank you guys

Comment: you can use [VectorAssembler](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.2/ml-features.html#vectorassembler).

Comment: @mtoto i used what you said ,i edited the code i got this error main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Data type StringType is not supported.Any help

Comment: all your cols should be numeric

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `array` function and then map into `LabeledPoint`s:

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vectors
import org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.LabeledPoint
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.DoubleType

// create an array column from all but first one:
val arrayCol: Column = array(df.columns.drop(1).map(col).map(_.cast(DoubleType)): _*)

// select array column and first column, and map into LabeledPoints
val result: Dataset[LabeledPoint] = df.select(col("col1").cast(DoubleType), arrayCol)
  .map(r => LabeledPoint(
    r.getAs[Double](0),
    Vectors.dense(r.getAs[mutable.WrappedArray[Double]](1).toArray)
  ))

// You can use the Dataset or the RDD
result.show()
// +-----+---------------------+
// |label|features             |
// +-----+---------------------+
// |1.0  |[2.0,3.0,4.0,0.5]    |
// |11.0 |[12.0,13.0,14.0,15.0]|
// |21.0 |[22.0,23.0,24.0,25.0]|
// +-----+---------------------+

result.rdd.foreach(println)
// (1.0,[2.0,3.0,4.0,0.5])
// (21.0,[22.0,23.0,24.0,25.0])
```

Comment: Please what are the import package you used thnx for your help,am trying your code Thnx again

Comment: Sorry my friend am new to scala and spark , i got an error telling me that $ is not a member of StringContext thnx in advance

Comment: Oh, that's another missing import (`import sparkSession.implicits._`), add that or replace `$"col1"` with `col("col1")`

Comment: HI my friend , i do not know how to thank you .but can you do me a favor , how can alter your code to transform my data into double ? thanks very much,

Comment: "i do not know how to thank you" - that's what the Accept button is for ;) to convert a column to double, you can use `cast(DoubleType)` - I updated the answer once more, although I do recommend you just read the DataFrame documentation, it's all there - I won't keep editing the answer per your requirements...

Comment: Thanks you my friend best regards

Comment: My friend i have a last issue, when i took result dataframe as input for the logisticregression model on spark ml i got equirement failed: Column features must be of type org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.VectorUDT@3bfc3ba7 but was actually org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.VectorUDT@f71b0bce. it is not the case wheni use the logitistic regression through the spark mlib, what should i do to use the spark ml api thnx

Comment: try changing the packages of LabeledPoint and Vectors in the **imports** as suggested by this (clear and detailed) error message: "ml" instead of "mllib"

Answer (score 0):

```
I have wrote code to convert dataframe's numeric columns into dense vector. Please find below code. Note: here col1 and col2 are numeric type columns.

import sparksession.implicits._;
   val result: Dataset[LabeledPoint] = df.map{ x => LabeledPoint(x.getAs[Integer]("Col1").toDouble, Vectors.dense(x.getAs[Double]("col2"))) }
   result.show();
result.printSchema();

+-------+----------+
|  label|  features|
+-------+----------+
|31825.0| [75000.0]|
|58784.0| [24044.0]|
|  121.0| [41000.0]|

root
 |-- label: double (nullable = true)
 |-- features: vector (nullable = true)
```